# How do I print the same output multiple times, horizontally and vertically, in a grid?

Tags: java, for-loop

I can print a single pine tree of varying sizes, but how do I print an exact replica of it next to it and underneath it, in a grid, using only for loops? This project utilizes a scanner so that the User can vary the size and number of section each tree has. The last portion of the project allows the user to pick how many trees to print, horizontally(next to each other) and vertically(underneath it). The exact wording and an example: Program makes use of a third input to print a number of trees. Ex: When NUM_TREES is three, a 3x3 grid of trees is printed. Any tips or hints are helpful, thank you.

Here is the code I have to get a single tree:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PineTreeUpgrade {
    static int numSections;
    static int sectionSize;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        askTheUserForInput();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is your amazing creation! How artistic!");
        printTree();
        printStem();
    }

    public static void askTheUserForInput() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello, user!");
        System.out.println("How many section would you like in your pine tree?");
        numSections = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Great! How big would you like each section to be?");
        sectionSize = userInput.nextInt();    
    }

    public static void printTree() {
        for (int k = 0; k < numSections; k++) {
            //prints the next section, each one increasing in size
            for(int i = 0; i < sectionSize; i++) {
                //prints the spaces and number of stars in each section
                for (int j = i; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections - 1) - k; j++){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                System.out.print("/");

                for (int j = 0; j < i + k; j++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

                System.out.print("*");

                for (int j = 0; j < i + k; j++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

                System.out.println("\\");

            }
        }

    }

    public static void printStem() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections -1) + 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println("|");

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections -1); j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.print("___");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How close do you want the trees?

Comment: One space separating each tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PineTreeUpgrade {
    static int numSections;
    static int sectionSize;
    static int gridSize;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        askTheUserForInput();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is your amazing creation! How artistic!");
        for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
            printTree();
            printStem();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void askTheUserForInput() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello, user!");
        System.out.println("How many section would you like in your pine tree?");
        numSections = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Great! How big would you like each section to be?");
        sectionSize = userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What grid size do you want?");
        gridSize = userInput.nextInt();
    }

    public static void printTree() {
        for (int k = 0; k < numSections; k++) {
            //prints the next section, each one increasing in size
            for(int i = 0; i < sectionSize; i++) {
                //prints the spaces and number of stars in each section
                for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
                    for (int j = i; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections - 1) - k; j++){
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }

                    System.out.print("/");

                    for (int j = 0; j < i + k; j++) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }

                    System.out.print("*");

                    for (int j = 0; j < i + k; j++) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }

                    System.out.print("\\");
                    int width = 2 * (sectionSize + numSections - 1) + 1;
                    if(x != gridSize - 1){
                        for(int y = sectionSize + numSections + k + i; y < width; y++)
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();

            }
        }

    }

    public static void printStem() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
                for (int j = 0; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections -1) + 1; j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                System.out.print("|");

                if(x != gridSize - 1)
                    for (int j = 0; j <= sectionSize + numSections; j++)
                        System.out.print(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
                for (int j = 0; j < (sectionSize - 1) + (numSections -1); j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                System.out.print("___");

                if(x != gridSize - 1)
                    for (int j = 0; j < sectionSize + numSections; j++) 
                        System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned about if statements yet, could you explain what you did with those, and what if statements do please?

Comment: What I did was create a loop that repeats `gridSize` times, and the if statement checks if this iteration is not the last iteration of the loop, to print the extra spaces only when the tree being printed is not the last tree in the line.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without if statements?

Comment: You can get rid of the if statement and keep that for loop, that way you'll end up printing the spaces after every single tree including the ones in the end of a line.

Comment: so the if statement is only there so you don't add extra spaces at the end? I understand the for loop inside it, I'm just not entirely sure of the purpose of the if statement.

Comment: Correct, the if statement is just to not add extra spaces at the end,

Answer (score 0):

width_of_double_pine_tree = 2 * width_of_single_pine_tree + buffer_between_trees

For loops don't have to define a variable, they can use an existing one.

```
int j = 0;
for(; j < (width_of_double_pine_tree - (width_of_single_pine_tree + buffer_between_trees)); j++)
//this is your first tree
for(; j < (width_of_double_pine_tree - width_of_single_pine_tree); j++)
//this is your buffer (S.o.p spaces)
for(; j < (width_of_double_pine_tree); j++)
//this is your second tree
```

Your canvas is always a rectangle, you subtract from it, the edge spaces you aren't using, void space with spaces (tabs ruin everything, because they aren't uniform, use spaces in everything!)

Use your i variable to keep track of the height that you're currently painting on your canvas so you can math in your pine needles and trunk. For the second tree, in the math portion, offset your j by the buffer_between_trees and width_of_single_tree `if(i < (j + buffer + width))`, etc.

Make sure you do the assignment before you tackle extra stuff.